# Why is getAdapterPosition() being stuck on the first view clicked every (say) 5 seconds?

Tags: java, android, class, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a RecyclerView class (QuestionCardAdapter) that presents all the items of a SpanishQuestionSet as CardViews.

Everything had been working fine (for instance i could make it so when a card was clicked, 'tick' and 'cross' buttons would come up and would remove the card when clicked)

However recently I wanted the clicking of the buttons (vCross or VTick) to modify an array which is a part of the SpanishQuestionSet (i.e. the item in the array would be +1 for wrong and -1 for right so that the descending quicksort i use will cause questions answered incorrectly to be at the top).

However, whenever I say click 4 consecutive cards as wrong, instead of each card's score being increased by 1, the first card of the 4's score is increased by 4. It seems like getAdapterPosition() is delayed. Could it be affected by a time limit variable I added so that the app wouldnt crash if someone double clicked a button before the card remove animation had completed?

Any help would be appreciated and I will present below the adapter and SpanishQuestionSet classes.

The adapter class is most likely the focus.

```
package com.alexgower.odin_spanishpack;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

public class QuestionCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionCardAdapter.QuestionCardViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
protected List<QuestionCardInfo> questionCardList;
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
private SpanishQuestionSet questionSet;
private int positionClicked;

private void setPositionClicked(int i){
    this.positionClicked =i;
}
private int getPositionClicked(){
    return this.positionClicked;
}

public QuestionCardAdapter(Context contextIn, List<QuestionCardInfo> questionCardList, SpanishQuestionSet questionSetIn) {
    this.questionCardList = questionCardList;
    this.context = contextIn;
    this.questionSet = questionSetIn;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionCardList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(QuestionCardViewHolder questionCardViewHolder, int i) {
    QuestionCardInfo ci = questionCardList.get(i);
    questionCardViewHolder.vQuestionAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(ci.score) + ci.question);
    questionCardViewHolder.answer = ci.answer;


    questionCardViewHolder.vTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    questionCardViewHolder.vCross.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    questionCardViewHolder.vColorTV.setBackgroundColor(questionSet.getColourForScore(context,ci.score));

}

@Override
public QuestionCardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.question_card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new QuestionCardViewHolder(itemView);
}



public class QuestionCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;


    protected TextView vQuestionAnswer;
    protected TextView vColorTV;
    protected ImageView vTick;
    protected ImageView vCross;
    protected String answer = "Error";

    public QuestionCardViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        vColorTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.forNowColourTextView);
        vQuestionAnswer =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.questionAnswerTextView);
        vTick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tickImage);
        vCross = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.crossImage);

        view = v;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                vQuestionAnswer.setText(answer);
                vTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vCross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setPositionClicked(getAdapterPosition());

            }

        });

        view = vTick;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime > 1000) {

                    questionSet.questionRight(getPositionClicked(),context);
                    //questionSet.saveScores(context);
                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(questionSet.getScore(getPositionClicked())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    removeAt(getPositionClicked());
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                }

            }

        });

        view = vCross;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime > 1000) {

                    questionSet.questionWrong(getPositionClicked(),context);

                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(questionSet.getScore(getPositionClicked())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    removeAt(getPositionClicked());
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                }

            }

        });


    }

}


public void testContext(int position) {
    questionSet.testFile(position, context);
    //String name = questionSet.getQuestion(position);
    //try {
    //    context.openFileOutput("a.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}
}

public void removeAt(int position) {
    questionCardList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, questionCardList.size());
}
```

SpanishQuestionSet class

```
package com.alexgower.odin_spanishpack;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

public class QuestionCardAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionCardAdapter.QuestionCardViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
protected List<QuestionCardInfo> questionCardList;
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
private SpanishQuestionSet questionSet;
private int positionClicked;

private void setPositionClicked(int i){
    this.positionClicked =i;
}
private int getPositionClicked(){
    return this.positionClicked;
}

public QuestionCardAdapter(Context contextIn, List<QuestionCardInfo> questionCardList, SpanishQuestionSet questionSetIn) {
    this.questionCardList = questionCardList;
    this.context = contextIn;
    this.questionSet = questionSetIn;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionCardList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(QuestionCardViewHolder questionCardViewHolder, int i) {
    QuestionCardInfo ci = questionCardList.get(i);
    questionCardViewHolder.vQuestionAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(ci.score) + ci.question);
    questionCardViewHolder.answer = ci.answer;


    questionCardViewHolder.vTick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    questionCardViewHolder.vCross.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    questionCardViewHolder.vColorTV.setBackgroundColor(questionSet.getColourForScore(context,ci.score));

}

@Override
public QuestionCardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.question_card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new QuestionCardViewHolder(itemView);
}



public class QuestionCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;


    protected TextView vQuestionAnswer;
    protected TextView vColorTV;
    protected ImageView vTick;
    protected ImageView vCross;
    protected String answer = "Error";

    public QuestionCardViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        vColorTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.forNowColourTextView);
        vQuestionAnswer =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.questionAnswerTextView);
        vTick = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tickImage);
        vCross = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.crossImage);

        view = v;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                vQuestionAnswer.setText(answer);
                vTick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vCross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setPositionClicked(getAdapterPosition());

            }

        });

        view = vTick;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime > 1000) {

                    questionSet.questionRight(getPositionClicked(),context);
                    //questionSet.saveScores(context);
                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(questionSet.getScore(getPositionClicked())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    removeAt(getPositionClicked());
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                }

            }

        });

        view = vCross;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime > 1000) {

                    questionSet.questionWrong(getPositionClicked(),context);

                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(questionSet.getScore(getPositionClicked())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    removeAt(getPositionClicked());
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                }

            }

        });


    }

}


public void testContext(int position) {
    questionSet.testFile(position, context);
    //String name = questionSet.getQuestion(position);
    //try {
    //    context.openFileOutput("a.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}
}

public void removeAt(int position) {
    questionCardList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, questionCardList.size());
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is quite easy. For anyone in the future with a similar problem, note that getAdapterView() simply returns the integer of a views position in the viewholder so when a view is removed, the next view takes its position.

i.e. if you have views 1,2,3,4,5. When you remove 2, 3 becomes 2 and 4 becomes 3 etc. Alternative explanation: whichever is the 5th view on the screen will have position 5, even if 10000 other items before it have been removed (it will not be position 10005).

So it was not a problem with getAdapterPostion(). To fix the problem I used a variable for an itemID for each view in the recyclerview and did not use getAdapterPosition() except for in the removeAt() method.